# black screen after press back button

Tags: android, android-activity

My app contains only one activity and ads activity. It works well, but when I press "Back" button my application is closed and I can see, instead of wallpaper, black background which is partly rolled down. I can see all icons as well. Then black part of screen disappears and I can see my normal screen wallpaper. It takes only less than a second but it is annoying. I can't found what the problem is it.

My activity has only horizontal orientation and has correct life cycle (`onPause-onStop-onDestroy`) after pressing back button. Ads activity is not launched at all.

I did not override `onPause() onStop() onDestroy()`.

My Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_transp_bkg"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/PlayTheme2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

Could it be related to back stack and trying to search some previous activity?

Please, put me on the right way to solve the problem. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Where is your Crash log? where is your Code? without any code or any crash report we can't guess the actual problem. Have a look [mcve]

Comment: There is no any crash in log. The process ended by onDestoy. What part of code I can put there to help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnBackPressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // what you want to do when back button is pressed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the OnBackPressed method in the activity

```
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed(){
        finish();
        }
```

And call on the FINISH method, this will properly close both your activity and app.

Comment: does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried it running on any other device or emulator with different sdk?

Comment: The same thing, in exception Android 8.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Back-Stack and Trying to search some previous activity.
Ovverride the onBackPressed with a Call to Finish to End Both.

```
public void onBackPressed(){
  finish();
}
```